# ggplot geom_text is messing up text order when using R mathematical notation

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, mathematical-typesetting

I am trying to label points in `ggplot` using `geom_text`. I would like to use R mathematical notation for the labelling. For example, a point at the x-coordinate 0.5 should have the label *1/2=0.5*, where  1/2 is written as a fraction. I have been trying this code:

```r
ggplot(data=NULL) +
  geom_point(aes(x=0.5, y=0)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=0.5, y=-0.1,
                label = paste("frac(1,2)"," = ", 1/2)), parse=TRUE) +
  xlim(-1,1) +
  ylim(-1, 1)
```

However, the order of the label is messed up, as the picture below shows:

[image: Messy order of the label text]

Instead of *1/2=0.5*, I receive *=(1/2,0.5)*. How can I obtain the correct order when using `frac()` in my label text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `label` outside `aes` and use double `==`, like it is said in  `help("plotmath")`.

```
ggplot(data=NULL) +
  geom_point(aes(x=0.5, y=0)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=0.5, y=-0.1),
            label = paste("frac(1, 2) == ", 1/2), parse=TRUE) +
  xlim(-1,1) +
  ylim(-1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is easily adaptable to the case where I want to replace numbers by variables. Thank you! `a = 3; ggplot(data=NULL) + geom_point(aes(x=0.5, y=0)) + geom_text(aes(x=0.5, y=-0.1), label = paste("frac(",a,",2) ==", a/2), parse=TRUE) + xlim(-1,1) + ylim(-1, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Your `label` should be placed outside of `aes()`.

```
ggplot(data=NULL) +
  geom_point(aes(x=0.5, y=0)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=0.5, y=-0.1),
                label = expression(paste(frac(1,2), " = ", 0.5))) +
  xlim(-1,1) +
  ylim(-1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a possibility to adapt this so that it works with variables as well. Let's say I replace the 1 in the example with `a` and initialize `a=3` earlier on. Is there a way to obtaIn `3/2=1.5` and not `a/2=a/2`?