# Is it possible to use == twice in R mathematical notation?

Tags: r, plotmath, mathematical-notation

I am trying to use R mathematical notation of `plotmath` in a plot label. In the label, I am trying to use to equality signs, e.g.

```r
ggplot(data=NULL) +
  geom_point(aes(x=0.5, y=0)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=0.5, y=-0.1),
            label = paste("x == frac(3,2) == 1.5"), parse=TRUE) +
  xlim(-1,1) +
  ylim(-1, 1)
```

However, I obtain the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = text[[i]]) : <text>:1:16: Unexpected '=='
1: x == frac(3,2) ==
                   ^
```

Is it possible to use two equality signs within a label?

(This is a follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70924250/ggplot-geom-text-is-messing-up-text-order-when-using-r-mathematical-notation).)

Comment: Yes, but you need to break your logical expression into two sub-expressions.  Try `x == frac(3,2) &  x == 1.5` or similar.

Comment: I'd call that a no, but I think the point gets across

Comment: Thank you very much.
@Limey, note that `==` is parsed into a mathematical equality sign = in plotmath notation.  Your suggestion does not solve my problem.
@shs, I am not sure whether I understand you correctly. Do mean that it is impossible to achieve what I am asking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot(NULL) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 0.5, y = 0)) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = -0.2, label = expression(paste("x = ", frac(3, 2), " = 1.5"))) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0.2,  label = "~x == ~frac(3, 2) == ~1.5", parse = T) +
  annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = -0.4, label = expression({x == frac(3, 2)} == 1.5)) +
  xlim(-1, 1) +
  ylim(-1, 1)
```

Comment: Added a third one, more elegant, using an empty grouping `label = expression({x == frac(3, 2)} == 1.5)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `paste` to join the two statements, though you might need to cheat by having a blank variable name on the left hand side of your second expression.

```r
ggplot(data=NULL) +
  geom_point(aes(x=0.5, y=0)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=0.5, y=-0.1),
            label = paste("paste(x == frac(3,2), ` ` == 1.5)"), parse=TRUE) +
  xlim(-1,1) +
  ylim(-1, 1)
```

[image]